Separate index.html and bundle files using nx webpack plugin
I'm using NxWebpackPlugin and I'm confused.
Is there any way to configure NX so that the assembly puts the files in the assets folder and index.html remains in the root dir?
example what I mean
dist
 |
 | assets
   | main.js
   | main.css
 | index.html

